# Cauchy sequences applied to metrics

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am looking for advice on if I have approached this problem correctly:
[image: Problem]

Here is what I have come up with:
[image]

Comment: Looks good to me. To make the last step more rigorous and formal, you may have to introduce some $\varepsilon$ and show that with an appropriate choice of $N$ the last sum is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.

Answer (score 2):

assume $0<m<n$

$\int_0^1 |f_n(t) - f_m(t)|\ dt = 3\frac {n-m}{2nm}< \frac {3}{2} \frac {1}{m}$